$\sum_{m=0}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^{100} \cdot (\frac{2}{9})^m \cdot \binom{100+2m}{m}=3$
According to Wolfram Alpha, the infinite sum $\sum_{m=0}^\infty (\frac{2}{3})^{100} \cdot (\frac{2}{9})^m \cdot \binom{100+2m}{m}$ evaluates to $3$.
How can one show that? I don't have any idea how to start here.

Seems like you want to find the generating function for $$F(z)=\sum_{n} \binom{100+2m}mz^m.$$ and show $F(2/9)=3^{101}/2^{100}.$ Not sure how to do that.

First of all define
$$f(x) = \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{100}\sum_m\binom{2m+100}{m}x^m$$
using the identity I recently found here (very useful resource btw), we have evaluating the convergent power series
$$f(x) = \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\bigg)^{100}$$
we need to evaluate this in $x=\frac{2}9$
$$f\bigg(\frac{2}9\bigg) =  \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{100} \cdot 3 \cdot \bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^{100} = 3$$
As desired hope this helps!

I found the same one on the Wolfram page : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html. It seems to come from a 1968 book by Prudnikov et al. "Integrals and Series: elementary functions", but I can't find it online. Hope this reference can help anyway.

Thank you for your answer. But how would one show that $f(x) = \bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^{100} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}}\bigg(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\bigg)^{100}$

@Martin Actually I was very curious about that and I've asked the same  question and after some research I found a way!

Thanks. I think it is somewhat impressive how much work goes into an equation that is relatively easy-looking.

Probably too advanced
$$I_k=\sum_{m=0}^\infty \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k} \, \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^m \, \binom{k+2m}{m}=\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{k} \,\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^m \, \binom{k+2m}{m}$$ Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty  \left(\frac{2}{9}\right)^m \, \binom{k+2m}{m}=\, _2F_1\left(\frac{k+1}{2},\frac{k+2}{2};k+1;\frac{8}{9}\right)=2^{-k}\, 3^{k+1}$$
So, $\forall k \geq 0$, $I_k=3$.
Could you use induction ?

Thanks for ypur answer. Could you tell me how one shows that $_2F_1\left(\frac{k+1}{2},\frac{k+2}{2};k+1;\frac{8}{9}\right)=2^{-k}, 3^{k+1}$?
